# Parsing parameters in subclass before calling constructor of the superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, superclass

```java
public Subclass(String[] parameters) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    super("Rectangle",
        Double.parseDouble(parameters[0]),
    Double.parseDouble(parameters[1]),
    90,
    Double.parseDouble(parameters[2]),
    Double.parseDouble(parameters[3]));
            if(parameters.length != 4) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla, bla");
    if(parameters == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla, bla");
}
```

I would like to put these 2 if statements before calling super-constructor. I know that I can't do that, so what's the painless way to do that kind of parsing of parameters (throwing `Exception`) before calling `super()`?

Comment: Wow! What a speed, thanks guys! I'm not familiar with factories yet, though...

Comment: The links will help - the Builder link is very easy to follow. In both cases you effectively give another class responsibility for creating new instances of the object you want instead of calling the constructor directly with the 'new' keyword. In that other class you can do whatever parameter and state validation you want.

Comment: Your code will already throw NullPointerException of ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in case parameter is null or has length smaller 4. Aren't these Exceptions more specific/detailed than an IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann I'm solving some kind of practice problems, not a real world task - but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems just better and neater to be able to check the parameters first, but if not possible I don't see a real problem with throwing the IllegalArgumentException after calling super(). I think it may be better than introducing some uncalled-for complexity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare a validation method taking `String[]` and returning it:

```
private static String[] validate(String[] param) {
    // do validation here
    return param;
}
```

And call it when using `param` first time

```
super("Rectangle", Double.parseDouble(validate(param).parameters[0]),
```

This trick solves problem quickly, but, as another poster noted, sometimes it's better to refactor your API (like creating a factory method).

Comment: Validate should be declared with "throws"? Nvm, I'll compile and see :). Thanks!

Comment: @make - `IllegalArgumentException` is unchecked, so `validate` does not need a `throws` list.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a factory pattern (for example an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)) to create a factory object from which new instances are obtained. The factory class method to obtain new instances could then throw bad argument exceptions before calling the (private) constructor of the real subclass.

You could also use a [Builder pattern](http://rwhansen.blogspot.com/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html) to verify parameters before creating and returning a new instance. You create a builder object (often an inner class, so that it has access to the outer class's private constructor etc.), set its properties and call a `build()` method - that method can then do any verification you need before returning you a new instance.

Comment: yet another benefit of static methods over builders